# What type of post hoc test does a LME use by default?

Tags: r, post-hoc, lme4-nlme

I need to know what type of post hoc test a LME model is using in R, by default? Is it Tukey? And is the alpha modified?

Comment: In any software? By default? Do you mean Tukey? (You tend to get a good answer here according to whether you ask a good question, specific and clear.)

Comment: Sorry, yes Tukey. I used to ran LME models in R and got informed that this model doesn't need a post-hoc test afterwards because it is already part of the model. Now, I need to specify which post-hoc test LME is using and if the alpha is being modified as well. Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You would need to specify the package & code as well. Linear mixed effects models (I assume that's what you mean by "LME", but you should spell out the acronyms you use) can be fit in nlme & lme4, at a minimum. So far as I know, neither automatically includes post-hoc tests. You should state where you heard that. At any rate, what R does by default is a good question for the r-help listservs (there is a mixed models specific one), but is off-topic for CV.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It was lme4. It has been a while (3yrs ago that I have used this, so I'm a bit rusted as which info you guys need in order to help me). I just learned by someone else that indeed it is not a post-hoc test but by changing the contrasts (the reference factor), the level of reference is compared to all the other references and that, is maintaining the alpha to 0.05. (not sure i'm clear, trying to translate from french to english...). :s

Comment: Use package multcomp to conduct post-hoc tests for lme4 models.